# Password matching with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm using java.util.regex.Pattern to match passwords that meet the following criteria:

1. At least 7 characters
2. Must consist of only letters and digits
3. At least one letter and at least one digit

I have 1 & 2 covered, but I can't think of how to do 3.

1 & 2 - `[\\w]{7,}`

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to use a single regex to match all 3 criteria?

Comment: Not really, but I thought it'd be cool if possible. If not just lemme know >.<

Comment: You have a problem... you decide to use regular expressions... now you have two problems :-) (A famous saying here at our company.) Sadly, I actually use them all the time!

Comment: Haha. Regexps are awesome imho :)
But yeah they can get pretty complicated. I'm not at that stage yet though >.<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this. This basically uses [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for achieving the 3rd requirement.

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w{7,}
```

or the Java string

```
"(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\\w{7,}"
```

**Explanation**

```
"(?=" +         // Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   "." +           // Match any single character
      "*" +           // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   "\\d" +          // Match a single digit 0..9
")" +
"(?=" +         // Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   "." +           // Match any single character
      "*" +           // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"[a-zA-Z]" +       // Match a single character present in the list below
                     // A character in the range between “a” and “z”
                     // A character in the range between “A” and “Z”
")" +
"\\w" +          // Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores)
   "{7,}"          // Between 7 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

**Edit**

If you want to include unicode letter support, then use this

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*\pL)[\pL\d]{7,}
```

Comment: It worked, very nice :)
Now i don't know which answer to accept :P

Comment: @lelouch if you want to exclude `_` then don't use `\w`, use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: Main issue I have with Regex solutions is that it is really bad at handling unicode characters and actually categorizing them as a letter. Only picking up on a-z is _never_ a good idea in any kind of important code.

Comment: @Stmated Agreed, but luckily Java has unicode support as part of its Regex implementation. For ex, this one can support unicode `(?=.*\d)(?=.*\pL)[\pL\d]{7,}`

Comment: Oh, did not actually know that. Might come in handy. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this with only Regex will very easily become convoluted and very difficult to understand/read if you ever need to change the credentials for a password.

Instead iterate over the password in a loop and count the different types of characters and then do simple if-checks.

Such as (untested):

```
if (password.length() < 7) return false;
int countDigit = 0;
int countLetter = 0;
for (int i = 0; password.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i)) {
        countDigit++;
    }
    else if (Character.isLetter(password.charAt(i)) {
        countLetter++;
    }
}

if (countDigit == 0 || countLetter == 0) {
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: FWIW, I think you're wrong - a _single_ regexp would be hard, but a combination of a few small simple regexps can be very expressive, and easily extended, whereas it would be quite hard to extend this method to encompass new constraints.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." - James Zawinski

Answer (score 1):

You won't need a character class for using `\w`, it is a character class by itself. However it also matches underscore which you didn't mention. So it might be better to use a custom character class.

To the "at least one" part, use look aheads:

```
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]{7,}/
```

You may need to add some extra escapes to make it work with Java*.

** <sup>which unfortunately I can't help!</sup>*

Comment: Oops. Yeah I totally forgot about the underscore. Thanks for the heads up >.<

Answer (score 1):

It's *possible* to do this in a single regexp, but I wouldn't as it'll be hard to maintain.

I would just do:

```
if (pass.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}") &&
    pass.matches("[a-zA-Z]") &&
    pass.matches("\\d"))
{
    // password is OK
}
```

It then becomes obvious how to apply additional constraints to the password - they just get added on with additional `&& ...` clauses.

NB: I've deliberately used `[a-z]` rather than `\w` because I'm unsure what happens to `\w`  if you use it in alternate locales where other characters might be considered "letters".

Answer (score 0):

I would add another regex to cover the 3rd criteria (you don't have to nail them all in one regex, but may want to combine them). I would go with somthing like `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`

taken from here- 
http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/