# Java Regex to match String password

Tags: java, regex

I have recently encountered this question in the text book:

I am suppose to write a method to check if a string have:

1. at least ten characters
2. only letters and digits
3. at least three digits

I am trying to solve it by Regx, rather than iterating through every character; this is what I got so far:

```
String regx = "[a-z0-9]{10,}";
```

But this only matches the first two conditions. How should I go about the 3rd condition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password matching with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257703/password-matching-with-regex)

Comment: Thank you so much, should have searched before asking ><

Answer (score 4):

You could use a *positive lookahead* for 3rd condition, like this:

```
^(?=(?:.*\d){3,})[a-z0-9]{10,}$
```

- `^` indicates start of string.
- `(?= ... )` is the positive lookahead, which will search the whole string to match whatever is between `(?=` and `)`.
- `(?:.*\d){3,}` matches at least 3 digits anywhere in the string.

  - `.*\d` matches a digit preceded by any (or none) character (if omitted then only consecutive digits would match).
  - `{3,}` matches three or more of `.*\d`.
  - `(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group.
- `$` indicates end of string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation first. I am still a bit lost about the positive lookahead and ?: as this is my first time encountering them. My current understanding of them is the positive lookahead to allow (?:.*\d){3,} to search the whole string. and the ?: allows the .*\d{3} to match any three digits but not remembering them, so it does not contribute to the final {10,}

Comment: And this form of Regx can only be used with class Pattern in Java? Not with String class methods such as .matches() and .replaceAll()

Comment: @Anlinyang Yes, you got the lookahead right, and the `?:` allows to use parenthesis to group an expression (e.g. `.*\d`) without capturing it (you need to group ithe expresssion in order to apply `{3,}` on it). You could use the same expression without the `?:` and it will still work.

Comment: @Anlinyang I'm not sure, i'm not Java savvy, but s far as i understand String class methods accept simple regex, so i guess you will need to create a pattern first and match the string agsinst it.